# Trouble with JQuery- switching multiple images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, product, switching

http://feathertest.me.pn/test.php 
The above is the link to a website im working on.

**i have 2 main features:**

1. As i click on the thumbnails below, an enlarged version appears on the bigger box above. The code i used for this is:

   ```
   $(function(){
       $(".thumb").click(function(){
           var imagesrc = $(this).children().prop('src');
           $('.bigImg').attr('src', imagesrc);
       });
   });
   ```
2. On the right side i have tiny square tiles depicting the colors available. on clicking each colors, the broom images on the left side will change to display the selected color. The code i used that is:

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript">
       $(function() {
           $('#showdiv1').click(function() {
               $('div[id^=div]').hide();
               $('#div1').show();
           });
           $('#showdiv2').click(function() {
               $('div[id^=div]').hide();
               $('#div2').show();
           });

       $('#showdiv3').click(function() {
           $('div[id^=div]').hide();
           $('#div3').show();
       });

       $('#showdiv4').click(function() {
           $('div[id^=div]').hide();
           $('#div4').show();
       });
   })
   ```

**My problem:**
After i click on one of the thumbnails (enlarged version of the image is successfully displayed on the big box above) and then when i click on one of the color tiles, the broom images are successfully changing only for the thumbnails, however, the image in the big box is the last clicked image of the previous color. I want that image also to change to the chosen color.

my HTML code snippet (i've only displayed the code for two colors):

```
<div id="feather-prods" class="row">
                <div id="div1">
                <div id="prod-stop" class="col-md-5 col-sm-6 col-xs-8 col-xs-push-2 col-sm-push-1 col-md-push-1">
                    <div class="prod-img"><img id="tab1show" class="tab-content bigImg" src="images/broom/monara-pp-1.jpg" alt="feather, Purple monara broom"></div>

                    <div class="thumbnailImg">
                      <div id="tab1show" class="tab-content thumb"><img src="images/broom/monara-pp-1.jpg" alt="feather, Purple monara broom" border="0" width="100%" class="thumbImg" /></div>
                      <div id="tab1show" class="tab-content thumb"><img src="images/broom/monara-pp-2.jpg" alt="feather, Purple monara broom" border="0" width="100%" class="thumbImg" /></div>
                      <div id="tab1show" class="tab-content thumb"><img src="images/broom/monara-pp-3.jpg" alt="feather, Purple monara broom" border="0" width="100%" class="thumbImg" /></div>
                      <div id="tab1show" class="tab-content thumb"><img src="images/broom/monara-pp-4.jpg" alt="feather, Purple monara broom" border="0" width="100%" class="thumbImg" /></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>

                <div id="div2" style="display:none;" >
                <div id="prod-stop" class="col-md-5 col-sm-6 col-xs-8 col-xs-push-2 col-sm-push-1 col-md-push-1">
                    <div class="prod-img"><img id="tab2show" class="tab-content bigImg" src="images/broom/monara-b-1.jpg" alt="feather, black monara broom"></div>

                    <div class="thumbnailImg">
                      <div id="tab2show" class="tab-content thumb"><img src="images/broom/monara-b-1.jpg" alt="feather, black monara broom" border="0" width="100%" class="thumbImg" /></div>
                      <div id="tab2show" class="tab-content thumb"><img src="images/broom/monara-b-2.jpg" alt="feather, black monara broom" border="0" width="100%" class="thumbImg" /></div>
                      <div id="tab2show" class="tab-content thumb"><img src="images/broom/monara-b-3.jpg" alt="feather, black monara broom" border="0" width="100%" class="thumbImg" /></div>
                      <div id="tab2show" class="tab-content thumb"><img src="images/broom/monara-b-4.jpg" alt="feather, black monara broom" border="0" width="100%" class="thumbImg" /></div>
                    </div>
                </div><!-- prod images end -->
                </div>
</div>
```

Please Help.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: I would add an attribute to each of the thumbnails that allows you to keep track of some sort of selected index. Like a position attribute, i.e. `<img src="..." position="0" />` and as you're clicking through them, keep track of what item is currently selected in the position. Then when you click a different color, check what index you're on, and choose the corresponding image in the other color.

Comment: @JoshuaTerrill The problem is im not very good with Jquery and Javascript. so im not quiet sure how to do it.

Comment: Here is an example of what I mean: https://jsfiddle.net/v81dk4dp/1/ it's something that tracks the index and color. You can click each of the images, as well as click the purple or yellow text, and it switches to the equivalent one each time it's clicked. More complicated than Ray C's example, and it's a little glitchy. He also brought up a good point about the ID's. ID's are meant to be unique. Classes don't have to be.

Comment: @JoshuaTerrill thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this is because thumbnail click event is not produced in good way.
You set the bgimage src in following way:

```
$('.bigImg').attr('src', imagesrc);
```

and above code actually set the imagesrc for all .bigImg element in the document. So although you have switched to other div, you still see the last clicked image.

Please update the thumbnail click handler, so that it will only update specific .bigImg, like following:

```
$(function(){
    $(".thumb").click(function(){
        var imagesrc = $(this).children().prop('src');
        $('.bigImg', $(this).parent().parent()).attr('src', imagesrc);
    });
});
```

Also I see you have assigned `prod-stop` as ID for every div element, and I say, it is not a good idea to give same id to multiple elements. You 'd better change it to class name, or make id unique.

Comment: IT WORKED! thanks so much. and thanks for the tip. I used it to avoid the page scrolling right up each time i changed colors ---> test.php#prod-stop

Comment: not sure if its the most advisable technique though :P

Comment: @HazraHameed well.. it is reasonable solution, and if I were in your place, I would not do make 4 click handlers for color option div. You can assign custom attribute for each color picker, and then make a one click handler, and then inside of it, based on the attribute value, do something accordingly.